# VS 2017 always uses default language when using globalization

Tags: c#, localization, visual-studio-2017, translation, globalization

I have a program which runs in English and French. Within the project, I have a Resources folder which contains a Localization.resx file with English strings and a Localization.fr-FR.resx file with French strings.
[File setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EczkE.png)

When I run the French version, I have set Current Culture and Current UI Culture to fr-FR but when I run the program, the client queries Localization.Designer.cs to get the translated strings but I still get the English strings. [Here is an example of how I get the string from Localization.Designer.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWIW9.png). From debugging, I can see that resourceCulture is correctly set to French but the ResourceManager still returns the English version. Is there something I'm missing or any way I could have set this up wrong? Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Please review the [MCVE] guidance on posting code and [edit] the question accordingly. In particular no one know what you do to "set Current Culture and Current UI Culture to fr-FR".

Answer (score 0):

First, what is the type of your project?

Did you set [`Thread.CurrentUICulture Property Definition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.currentuiculture?view=net-5.0) and call [`ComponentResourceManager.ApplyResources Method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.componentresourcemanager.applyresources?view=net-5.0) to apply a resource's value to each control?

In order to access the resx file more conveniently, it is recommended to also create a resx file "en-US.resx" for "English".

Here is a winforms demo.

resx files:

[image]

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.Text == "en")
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
        ApplyResource();
    }
    if (comboBox1.Text == "fr")
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR");
        ApplyResource();
    }
}

private void ApplyResource()
{
    System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager res = new ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1));
    foreach (Control ctl in Controls)
    {
        res.ApplyResources(ctl, ctl.Name);
    }
    res.ApplyResources(this, "$this");
}
```

Test result:

[image]